# wait for multiple scala-async

Tags: java, scala, csv, async-await, sbt

i want to close csv writer when all the async block executed

```
import java.io.{FileReader, FileWriter}
import com.opencsv.{CSVReader, CSVWriter}
import org.jsoup.helper.StringUtil
import scala.async.Async.{async, await}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

var rows = 0
reader.forEach(line => {
  async {
    val csv = new CSV(line(0), line(1), line(2), line(3), line(4));
    entries(0) = csv.id
    entries(1) = csv.name
    val di = async(httpRequest(csv.id))
    var di2 = "not available"
    val di2Future = async(httpRequest(csv.name))
    di2 = await(di2Future)
    entries(2) = await(di)
    entries(3) = di2
    writer.writeNext(entries)
    println(s"${csv.id} completed!!!! ")
    rows += 1
  }
})
writer.close();
```

in above code writer always closed first, so i want to execute all async block then close my csv writer.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a skeleton solution.

```
  val allResponses = reader.map(l => {
    val entries = ??? // declare entires data structure here

    for {
      line <- async(l)
      // line <- Future.succesful(l)

      csv <- async {
        val csv = CSV(line(0), line(1), line(2), line(3), line(4))
        entries(0) = csv.id
        entries(1) = csv.name
        csv
      }

      di <- async {
        httpRequest(csv.id)
      }

      di2 <- async {
        httpRequest(csv.name)
      }

      e <- async {
        entries(2) = di
        entries(3) = di2

        entries
      }
    } yield e
  })

  val t = Future.sequence(allResponses)

  t.map(a => {
    val writer = new FileWriter("file.txt")
    a.foreach(i => {
      writer.writeNext(i)
    })

    writer.close()
  })
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: getting error at `Future.sequence(allResponses)` type mismatch, expected: NotIntferedM[Future[NotInferedA]] , actuval: Unit

Comment: @GovindSingh :  Compiler cannot infer the types of `reader` and `entries`.
Check your code. Its hard give the exact answer with the code you've provided. I created some dummy code to replicate your functions and it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

An `async` block produces a `Future[A]`, where `A` in your case is `Unit` (which is the type of the assignment `rows += 1`).

In general, you can perform operations when a `Future` is complete like the following:

```
def myFuture: Future[Something] = ??? // your async process

myFuture.onComplete {
  case Success(result) =>
    ???
  case Failure(exception) =>
    ???
}
```

If you want to perform something regardless the status you can skip pattern matching:

```
myFuture.onComplete(_ => writer.close()) // e.g.
```